# Is it a good thing create jquery plugins

Tags: jquery

So let's say i'm building a huge website, something close to facebook size, and i'm using jquery for most of the client side stuff, now obviously there is probably going to be at least 4k lines of code and thousands of ajax request etc..

So my question is fairly simple, what is the best way to build my jquery based scripts, should i create plugins for things that im going to use multiple times or should i just use functions  and call them whenever i need?

**EDIT** Well maybe i overdid it with `facebook size` but it's going to be pretty big anyways..

Comment: Plugins promote reuse. Thats the benefit of making them. A abstract function *can* be thought of as a plugin, just not in the `jQuery` way (e.g. via `$`). Just make sure you don't attach *everything* to `$`. P.s. I believe Facebook's compiled binary is 1.5GB. I'm not good at math, but I think thats a *lot* **lot** more than 4k LOC ;)

Comment: That depends entirely on your preferences. Obviously, plugins are more portable, but you have to be more careful about how you write them. Oh, and good luck on that "close to facebook size" thing.

Comment: This question probably belongs on either codereview or programmers, not on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin or function can accomplish the task just fine either way.  A plug-in makes sense if you have an operation that operates on one or more DOM objects like other jQuery methods.

A plug-in has the advantage that you can chain it more easily as in:

```
$(".myClass").myPlugin("x").addClass("foo");
```

And, it's a way to create a number of functions in the jQuery namespace without using the global namespace at all.  Other than that, there isn't a whole lot of difference between it and a function.

If you have a commonly used jQuery operation, then there is no downside to making it a plug-in and you gain the ability to chain method calls.

Answer (score 1):

In any sort of large-scale, thick-client (i.e. javascript-heavy), web application, you will probably need to really have a good handle on your javascript code base with regards to namespacing, scoping, etc.

I think plug-ins might be a tool in your tool chest in helping keep the global namespace clean, but you might also investigate frameworks like backbone.js that will allow you to free some of your javascript code constructs from the DOM altogether.

Other tools like underscore.js would likely be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your web site is such a big web site I recommend you to use [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) library beside jquery which implement MVVM pattern in java script.as you mentioned using jQuery for larg web site lead to huge numbers of lines of codes.I think with knockout.js you can reduce them and managed your  functions and callbacks better.
it's just a recommendation.